# What happens if I test positive for COVID in-transit at Doha Airport?

Tags: airports, covid-19, doha

I know that if you test positive at the departure airport, you won't be allowed on the plane. If you test positive at the arrival airport, you will probably be sent to isolation, either at home or somewhere else.

But ... what happens if you test positive at a in-transit airport!? You cannot go home since you have no home and you cannot leave the airport since you have no visa!

In my case specifically, the transit airport will be Doha Airport.. What happens if I test positive there?

Comment: I imagine you’d be put into mandatory quarantine in a government-controlled location until you tested negative and could resume your journey. You’d probably have to surrender your passport and would be under vigilance by the authorities until you board.  In effect, a similar situation to being caught up in a transit delay which meant you couldn’t remain airside.

Comment: Edited to specify Doha for you, as this will vary depending on which airport you go to.  Some don't even test in transit, for example.

Comment: [Does any international airport require passengers to take a COVID when transiting?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162684/1810)

Comment: The lack of a visa isn't inherently a problem, the same way that if you have a heart attack at the transit airport, they won't just leave you for dead because you don't have a visa. Any country, certainly a country that's host to a major international transit hub, is going to have some procedure for dealing with people who can't continue their travel for medical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You will not end up in this situation, since **transiting through Doha does not require taking a PCR test** on the spot.  [Qatar Airways](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-alerts/requirements.html):

> Transit through Doha
>
> Passengers who are transiting through Doha, and not leaving the
> airport, are not required to present any test results or
> certifications above the requirements of their departure or
> destination country.