# Does any international airport require passengers to take a COVID test when transiting?

Tags: air-travel, transit, international-travel, covid-19

I am not looking for a list of airports, but simply a yes/no answer, preferably with an example, so that I know whether to add this in my list of requirements to check before taking a flight that has a layover.

I am aware that:

- some transit airports (e.g., in Russia) require passengers to do a COVID test *prior* to departure (i.e., before entering the transit airport), but I wonder if any require passengers to do a COVID test *during* transit.
- in many (all?) cases, the COVID-19 requirements don't come from the airport but from the country authorities. Let's regard requirements from the country authorities as part of the airport requirements.

---

Response to comments:

> The [question below](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162683/what-happens-if-i-test-positive-for-covid-in-transit-at-doha-airport) assumes that this is the case – [Bernhard Döbler](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/33703/bernhard-d%c3%b6bler) [2 mins ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162684/does-any-international-airport-require-passengers-to-take-a-covid-when-transitin#comment407684_162684)

@BernhardDöbler no, could be optional, or only in some conditions (e.g. if the passenger shows some symptom of COVID-19). Also, I checked on IATA and didn't see such a requirement.

Comment: The [question below](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162683/what-happens-if-i-test-positive-for-covid-in-transit-at-doha-airport) assumes that this is the case

Comment: @BernhardDöbler no, could be optional. Also, I checked on IATA and didn't see such requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, due to newly discovered Covid-strains in UK, South Africa and Brazil, all international airports in India would take your sample if your flight is originating from the above-mentioned countries, you would only be allowed in your connecting flight if your sample is negative. The [complete procedure](https://boi.gov.in/sites/default/files/u4/Algorithmforinternationalarrivals.pdf) is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Wait, it says that if the test is negative you have to "home quarantine for 7 days and re-test". Does it mean I cannot take the connecting flight and have to quarantine in India? Or should I quarantine once arrived in the destination after the connecting flight? And if so, do they even have the authority to impose such a requirement?

Comment: @bracco23 India has suspended all regular international flight but they have established air-bubbles with a lot of countries. It seems that it is not possible to transit through India to some other country. The procedure attached in the answer above does not make sense for international transiting travelers. it is only meant for travelers who have to transit to another domestic airport in India.

Comment: But then this answer doesn’t fit this question as it’s about international transit?